# What does `포스근히` mean? Is this word used now?

Tags: word-usage

In my textbook, a word , '포스근히' is written.

This meaning seems to be `tender`, `soft`, and so on, according to the textbook.

This is a kind of adverb.

I searched this word on the web, but there was no result.

In my dictionary, neither.

Is this word used now?

**Update** `柔(やわ)らかく` means softly in Japanese.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"소월은 <님의 노래>에서 "내 잠은 포스근히 깊이 들어요"라는 표현을 한 바 있다. '포스근히'는 국어사전에 없는 말이다. 우리말을 정감 있게 끄집어낼 줄 알았던 소월에게서 나온 말이다." - http://www.ohmynews.com/NWS_Web/View/at_pg.aspx?CNTN_CD=A0002458159

It's not a word in Korean dictionary. It's a word coined by Sowol.

포근하다 - https://dict.naver.com/search.dict?dicQuery=%ED%8F%AC%EA%B7%BC%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4
[형용사]

1. 도톰한 물건이나 자리 따위가 보드랍고 따뜻하다.
2. 감정이나 분위기 따위가 보드랍고 따뜻하여 편안한 느낌이 있다.
3. 겨울 날씨가 바람이 없고 따뜻하다.
   [유의어] 따듯하다, 따뜻하다, 보드랍다
   포근하다
4. (느낌이) cozy, snug
5. (감정·분위기 등이) warm, tender
6. (날씨가) warm, (겨울에) mild

스 in 따스하다

- https://dict.naver.com/search.dict?dicQuery=%EB%94%B0%EC%8A%A4%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4
  [형용사] 조금 다습다. ‘다스하다’보다 센 느낌을 준다.
  [유의어] 다사롭다1, 다스하다, 따뜻하다

Answer (score 2):

I have been living in South Korea for 25 years but I never heard the word. It is probably 포근히. 포근히 means soft, tender, cozy or warm.

Could you double check the text book? Or, is the text book from North Korea? What is the name of the publisher?

Comment: Sorry, I mistook the word, but there was no result in my dictionary again. This word is rendered on the poem of Korean, 金素月。The poem is here;[http://raincat.com/modern_poetry/9930?ckattempt=1]

Comment: Re: Haru, I see! Do you see how the poem "님의 노래" is formulated? Sometimes Korean poets create or change some words in order to fit them in a format of a poem. If you think about 'Sonnet' in English poems, you may be able to understand why poets do that. It is to make the poem look better and it becomes like a song. There is no word '포스근히' in Korean but 김소월 changed the word 포근히 to 포스근히 in order to make the word fit in the format of the poem. Also, the new word sounds softer to me than 포근히.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I understand what you tell. In Japanese, many poets create new words in their  poems, too.Yes, I must think it when I read poets in foreign languages.